# Relationship between two distinct notions for divisors on curves

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I've seen divisors on curves before, a few years ago in a course in algebraic geometry. Now I've come across them again, but they're somewhat more generalized. I was hoping someone could explain the similarities/differences between the two notions.

The first notion (from Algebraic Curves by Fulton) says for any irreducible projective curve $C$, with nonsingular model $X$, a divisor on $X$ is a formal sum
$$ D = \sum_{P\in X} n_P P$$
where each $n_P\in \mathbb{Z}$ and all but finitely many are 0.

The second notion (from Algebraic Geometry by Milne) says for any normal, irreducible variety $V$, a divisor on $V$ can be written uniquely as a finite (formal) sum
$$ D = \sum n_i Z_i,$$
where the $Z_i$ are the irreducible subvarieties of $V$ of codimension 1 (prime divisors).

In the generalized case, when $V$ is a curve (i.e., dimension 1) then the $Z_i$ are 0 dimensional, so just points on the curve, and everything seems OK. But then we move on to the degree of a divisor. In Fulton, the degree of a divisor $\sum_{P\in X} n_P P$ is simply the sum of the coefficients, $\sum_{P\in X} n_P$. However, via Example 12.4 in Milne, the definition of a divisor is as follows:

Let $C$ be a curve. If $D = \sum n_i P_i$, then the intersection number
$$ (D) = \sum n_i[k(P_i):k].$$
By definition, this is the degree of $D$.

Now, we don't have any references for my class (as it's all over the place and would require about 10 minimum..), but this is how we defined the degree of a divisor for a curve in class (using the extension of $k(P_i)$ over $k$) and I'm confused. Is this suggesting that, by Fulton's definition, we have $[k(P_i):k] = 1$ for every point? Because if so, it seems silly to even bother putting that in. Now given Milne is actually writing the intersection number, I felt he could just leaving implicit that the $[k(P_i):k]$ are 1. However in class, we simply said a divisor is *blah* and its degree is *blahh* using the degree of the extensions, so there must be something non-trivial going on here!

Now the only thing I haven't entirely accounted for above, is the fact that in Fulton, a curve over a field $k$ is a set of points in $k^n$, whereas Milne is using algebraic varieties, which I'm not terribly well versed with. However, Milne makes note of the fact that there is a one-to-one correspondence between maximal ideals of $k[V]$ and one point sets of $V$, so I would expect, for each $P_i$ in Fulton's definition, there is a corresponding maximal ideal, so that a divisor should be identical, except replacing each $P_i$ with the corresponding maximal ideal.

Somewhat more troubling, I thought it was obvious at first, and didn't give it a second thought, but in retrospect, what *is* $[k(P_i):k]$? If $P_i$ is a subvariety of codimension 1, for a curve defined over $k$, then how can this not have to be 1? If nothing else, I'd also appreciate any additional references for these generalized divisors on curves (though I do like Milne's notes!). Thanks!

Comment: This is related to the fact that not every closed point is rational. For example, Fulton might assume you are over $\mathbb{C}$ or at least an algebraically closed field and hence $k(P_i)=k$, so the degree is always 1. In general, you only know that the local ring at a point modulo the maximal ideal is an algebraic extension of the base field, which may be non-trivial. If no one has posted an expanded version of this comment when I wake up tomorrow I'll expand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In a nutshell**, on page 35 Fulton states in the first sentence of the chapter  "From now on $k$ will be a fixed algebraically closed field". This implies that all $[k(P_i):k]=1$ so that his definition is compatible with yours and Milne's.

**In more detail**, Milne also supposes that his base field is algebraically closed in the first 10 chapters but in Chapter 11 he introduces varieties over an *arbitrary* field $k$.
This means that an affine varietie $V$ is  determined by some finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ and consists of the maximal ideals of $A$.
In practice $A=k[T_1,...,T_N]/\langle P_1, ...  ,P_r\rangle$ and we say that $V$ is the subvariety $V\subset \mathbb A^N_k$ determined by the equations $P_j\in k[T_1,...,T_N]$.
Given a point  $P\in V$ corresponding to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m\subset A$, the field  $\kappa(P)=A/\mathfrak m$ is a finite-dimensional extension of $k$ (this is a version of the Nullstellensatz and is not trivial) and its dimension $[\kappa(P):k]$ is the integer that you asked about
(I prefer to write  $\kappa(P)$, as in EGA and many texts in algebraic geometry, instead of $k(P)$ so as  to avoid confusion with the base field $k$)

**An example** Suppose you take $A=\mathbb R[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle$, that is you consider the circle $V\subset \mathbb A^2_{\mathbb R}$ of equation $X^2+Y^2-1=0$.
If you consider the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=\langle x-1,y \rangle\subset A=\mathbb R[x,y]$ corresponding to the good old point $P=(1,0)$ of the circle,  you get the unsurprising equality $[\kappa(P):\mathbb R]=1$,  since $\kappa(P)=\mathbb R[x,y]/\langle x-1,y\rangle=\mathbb R$.
However if you consider the point $Q$ corresponding the maximal ideal $\mathfrak n=\langle x-\sqrt 2,y^2+1\rangle\subset A=\mathbb R[x,y]$, you get $[\kappa(Q):\mathbb R]=2$ since $\kappa(Q)=\mathbb R[x,y]/\langle x-\sqrt 2,y^2+1\rangle\cong \mathbb C$.

**Edit**
Since Alex asks about this in his comment below: yes there is a relationship between the point $Q\in V$ and the two  points   $( \sqrt 2,\pm i)$ in the complexified circle $V_\mathbb C\subset \mathbb  A_\mathbb C^2$ corresponding to the $\mathbb C$-algebra $A\otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C=\mathbb C[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle$.
You can say that $\mathfrak n$ corresponds to  the orbit of either of these points under the action of the Galois group $Gal(\mathbb C/\mathbb R)$ on $V_\mathbb C$ or you can also say that $\mathfrak n$ is the common kernel of the two homomorphisms of $\mathbb R$-algebras $A\to \mathbb C$ sending $x\mapsto \sqrt 2$ and $y\mapsto \pm i$

Comment: !! That explains it! I looked through Chapter 8 of Fulton, along with all the areas he refers to for previous results, and couldn't find anything about $k$ being algebraically closed, but that settles that. Small question about the last part of the example, what is the point $Q$? If instead, $\mathfrak{n} = \langle x, y^2 + 1\rangle$ I'd say this corresponds to the point $(0,i)$, but the point $(\sqrt{3},i)$ isn't on the circle $V$, so am I missing something silly? Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Alex,  there was indeed a typo in my post : I meant $\sqrt 2$ where I had written $\sqrt 3$. I just corrected that: thanks a lot for being so attentive. I have also added a few words on the link with the complexified circle in an edit. This is a vast subject belonging to arithmetic geometry. The key concept you might look up some time  would be "closed points versus rational points".

Comment: Ah, great! Thanks again, and thanks for the extra bit in the edit (and reference :) )!